# Unwanted pointers modification

Tags: c, pointers

Situation: I'm currently working with chained lists and I am adding new elements through a function called `inputRegistering()`. I am positive that at the end of this function, an element have been added to the correct place.

Issue1: The added element modifies all the other to take its value.

Issue2: When exiting the function, and calling the `inputReadingAll()` function (which displays the list in its entirety), the elements are now all "empty", or replaced with gibberish (as can do the pointers).

Test1: I have tested to do a manual adding in the `main()` function and it seems everything worked fine. I can't understand what is the fundamental difference with my code though...

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLEN 256

typedef struct 
{
    struct elt *first;
    struct elt *last;
} Tfile;
typedef struct elt
{
    char *val;
    struct elt *next;
} Telt;

int fileAdd(Tfile *, char *);
void fileInit(Tfile *);

void inputReadingAll(Tfile *);
void inputRegistering(Tfile *);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    Tfile file;
    fileInit(&file);
    inputRegistering(&file);
    inputRegistering(&file);
    inputReadingAll(&file);
}

int fileAdd(Tfile *F, char *newVal){
    Telt *newElt;
    newElt = (Telt*)malloc(sizeof(Telt));
    if(newElt == NULL){
        printf("Error\n");
        return 0;
    }
    newElt->val = newVal;
    newElt->next = NULL;
    if(fileTaille(F) == 0)
        F->first = newElt;
    else
        F->last->next= newElt;
    F->last = newElt;
    return 1;
}
void fileInit(Tfile *F){
    F->first = NULL;
    F->last = NULL;
}

void inputReadingAll(Tfile *file){
    printf("> Reading all function\nBEGIN\n");
    Telt *currElt = file->first;
    while(currElt != NULL){
        printf("%p, %s\n", currElt, currElt->val);
        currElt = currElt->next;
    }
    printf("END\n");
}
void inputRegistering(Tfile *file){
    printf("> Registering function\n> What to register : \n> ");
    char temp[MAXLEN];
    fgets(temp, MAXLEN, stdin);
    temp[strcspn(temp, "\n")] = 0;
    printf("Registering %s\n", temp);
    fileAdd(file, temp);
}
```

Comment: This code generates a warning that is a certain bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (pointer to) local array `temp` of the function `inputRegistering()` is passed to the function `fileAdd()` and the pointer is directly stored to the structure.

This is bad because the array is local and it is invalidated on returning from the function `inputRegistering()`.

Instead of this, the function `fileAdd()` should copy the passed string and store the pointer to the copy in the structure.

This can be done like this:

```
newElt->val = malloc(strlen(newVal) + 1); /* +1 for terminating null-character */
if (newElt->val == NULL) {
    printf("Error\n");
    free(newElt);
    return 0;
}
strcpy(newElt->val, newVal);
```

instead of this:

```
newElt->val = newVal;
```

Comment: Or just use `strdup` instead of `malloc` and `strcpy`?

Comment: If the function is supported.

Comment: [Why would it not be supported?](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strdup)

Comment: @AdrianMole Perhaps because it is only standard since 2023.

Comment: @EmanuelP OK - That's a good point. I wasn't sure about it's status in terms of the Standard.